# Dynamically extracting the last part of a URL

Tags: java, string

I have a URL https://xyz.com/abc/.../xyz/name_part. I would like to efficently split this into 2 separate parts a Namespace URI that is https://xyz.com/abc/.../xyz and to a Name part which is the name_part in the URL. What is the best way of doing this in Java?
Note that the Namespace URI is not fixed and this can be dynamic.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that efficiency should be any concern in this. Go for what's most understandable:

```
String url = "https://xyz.com/abc/.../xyz/name_part";
int separator = url.lastIndexOf('/');
String namespacePart = url.substring(0, separator);
String namePart = url.substring(separator + 1);
```

or maybe:

```
String url = "https://xyz.com/abc/.../xyz/name_part";
String[] pathSegments = URI.create(url).getPath().split("/");
String namePart = pathSegments[pathSegments.length - 1];
String namespacePart = url.replaceAll("/" + namePart + "$", "");
```

depending on what seems most natural to you.

Answer (score 5):

From what I know, URL class of JDK can cater to your needs.

```
URL url = new URL("https://test:password@localhost:7001/context/document?key1=val1&key2=val2");
```

Check all the `getters` of URL class. some of them include:

```
url.getProtocol();
url.getUserInfo();
url.getHost();
url.getPort();
url.getPath();
url.getQuery();
```

Comment: Neither URL nor URI has a way of extracting the last path segment. Why is this answer so popular when it doesn't answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Use the URL class, it splits up a url in all the relevant parts: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

In this situation I would simply use regex

```
    String url = "https://xyz.com/abc/.../xyz/name_part";
    String[] a = url.split("/(?!.*/.*)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

output

```
[https://xyz.com/abc/.../xyz, name_part]
```